# Why the delimiters are used in CAN protocol

Tags: embedded, protocols, microcontroller, can-bus

What is the purpose of delimiters in CAN protocol .. As we know that there are CRC delimiter, ACK delimiter and so on.. Is there any specific purpose for this. Kindly help on this topic.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please have a read through this topic . I am not getting any clarification from any other sides. Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look [HERE](http://www.edaboard.com/thread178933.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "recessive" delimiter bits ensure that there are bit transitions in the fields that do not have bit-stuffing applied.  The bit transitions are necessary to recover timing synchronisation that might not be otherwise available due to NRZ encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 3):

CRC delimiter:
the ECU needs some time to calculate the CRC and hence a delimiter bit is introduced to buy some time for the ECU....

ACK delimiter:
the acknowledgement is sent from the receiving node to the transmitting node and it requires some time and hence ack delimiter is used.

Comment: its convening  my doubt regarding these Delimiter concept in CAN.

Answer (score 1):

**ACK Delimeter:**

The ACK delimiter is used to distinguish between ACK errors and CRC errors. If an error frame is placed on the bus immediately after the ACK bit, it indicates an ACK error. If an error frame is placed on the bus after the ACK delimiter slot, it indicates a CRC error.

It also provides the transmitting node with time to determine whether or not the frame was acknowledged by any other nodes and act accordingly.

A common misconception is that the ACK delimiter provides receiving nodes with time to calculate the ACK response. This is incorrect as receiving nodes are expected to ACK a received frame **during** the ACK bit slot - not after the ACK delimiter bit. References: [See part A page 23](https://www.kvaser.com/software/7330130980914/V1/can2spec.pdf).

**CRC delimiter:**

Provides the CAN controller with time to calculate the CRC value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).